# Can't make an output with a forEach function in a template string

Tags: javascript, dom, destructuring

```
const categoriesLght = document.querySelectorAll('#categories .item').length;
console.log(`There are ${categoriesLght} clasifications.`);
const h2s = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const heading = h2s.forEach(element =>
  console.log(`Clasification: ${element.textContent}`),
);

const quantity = document.querySelectorAll('h2 + ul');
quantity.forEach(el =>
  console.log(`Quantity: ${el.childElementCount}`),
);
```

Output:

```
There are 3 clasifications.
Clasification: Student
Clasification: Fish
Clasification: Rocket
Quantity: 3
Quantity: 5
Quantity: 6
```

If I try to put a function in a template string, there will be an error. Trying to find a way to make it happen. Desired output is:

```
Clasification: Student
Quantity: 3 
Clasification: Fish
Quantity: 5
Clasification: Rocket
Quantity: 6
```

And I'm looking for a way how to put a result of ForEach method in a template string, to make happen something like that (I think I'm looking for some destructurization):

```
str = [h2s.forEach, quantity.forEach]([category, count])=> (console.log(`Clasification: ${category.textContent},
Quantity: ${count.childElementCount} `));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try saving the values to variable first:

```
const clarifications = [];
const quantities = [];

const h2s = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const heading = h2s.forEach(element =>
    clarifications.push(element.textContent);
);

const quantity = document.querySelectorAll('h2 + ul');
quantity.forEach(el =>
    quantities.push(el.childElementCount);
);

clarifications.forEach((clarification, i) => {
    console.log('Clarification:', clarification);
    console.log('Quantity:', quantities[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over one and use the index to reference the other

```
const h2s = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const quantity = document.querySelectorAll('h2 + ul');

h2s.forEach((element, i) =>
  console.log(`Classification: ${element.textContent}, Quantity: ${quantity[i].childElementCount}`),
);
```

Comment: So the better solution is now 3 loops instead of one?